# Regular expression help

Tags: regex

What I have: `/^[26]{1}[0-9]{7}$/`

What I want to achieve:

```
25566778 # match
62299311 # match
12345678 # no match
76752313 # no match
```

Basicly, maximum length 8, first character can only be either 2 or 6, digits only.

What is wrong with this expression?

Comment: I can ask you the same - what *is* wrong with this expression? Why do you think it doesn't work? The only thing I see is that you say "maximum length 8", but the pattern accepts *exactly* 8.

Comment: Please post an example of the regex not working as you expect.

Comment: Should work fine as you have it.

Comment: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx and http://www.rubular.com/ both show that your pattern corrects matches (or not) all four of your examples.

Comment: See my comment on @bazmegakapa post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problem with your expression:

http://regexr.com?2u74v

Comment: Ah, I guess the multiline checkbox was essential there. Doesn't work without it, and that's where the problem was.

Comment: @Tom Yeah, without it `^` and `$` mean the start and end of the whole string respectively.

Answer (score 4):

A few observations:

- The `{1}` is unnecessary as it is assumed.
- You might have more luck with `\b` on the ends rather than `^` and `$` as those two match then end of the string while `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

  - Please explain your requirements for what's past the ends if those are a concern

Comment: I have no opinion regarding `\b` ( I prefer `^` and `$` but have no reason for that preference), but +1 for `"{1} is unnecessary"`

Answer (score 2):

It's correct. Simplify: `^[26][0-9]{7}$`

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this as `^[26]\d{0,7}$`. BTW, a tool which has helped me a LOT in designing my regexs is [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I would do a few things

- specify in what context you are using the regular expression--this is
  important. Different environments can have different syntax, and
  while not so much in this case, different capabilities. (+|-)
  Lookbheinds or lookaheads, for example.
- remove the /'s unless necessary
- remove the `{1}` after [26], 1 is implied.
- Make sure the line ends after the last digit. Otherwise the match will fail with the `$` specified. No
        spaces, No comments, etc.

with all that said using `grep` this worked:

`grep -P '^[26][0-9]{7}$' temp`

(note, -E would work as well)

with the following output:

> 25566778
>  62299311

*edit* 6 other answers while I answer my question. What did I expect. I hope this helps

Answer (score -5):

Try with regular expression:

```
/^[26]{2}\d{7}$/
```

Comment: -1  He is using a regex, and this pattern doesn't satisfy any of his requirements.

Comment: you could do `\d{7}$` + would match 2-N and the OP may not want numbers long than 8 places.